# Hive Query Language RLIKE Query

Tags: regex, hive

I'm trying to query with the following query

```
select * from mytable where mycolumn rlike '\d~[\d\.]+~\d~[\d\.]+~\d~2~(33|44)`
```

Here's some sample data in mytable

```
id | mycolumn
---|--------------------------------
1  | 1~2.3.1~9~333.2~3~2~33
2  | 1~1.4.3~4~233.2~4~2~44
3  | 1~53.0.2785.124~4~6.0.1~5~2~33
4  | 1~3~3~3~3~6~3
```

However, the result is always empty.

As stated in [Hive Query Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF),

> NULL if A or B is NULL, TRUE if any (possibly empty) substring of A matches the Java regular expression B, otherwise FALSE. For example, 'foobar' RLIKE 'foo' evaluates to TRUE and so does 'foobar' RLIKE '^f.*r$'.

I tested the RegExp in Java, it works fine. Also tried to replace `\` with `\\`, and tried to replace `~` with `\~`, but there was no luck.

The Java code I used to test is as follows

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d~[\\d\\.]+~\\d~[\\d\\.]+~\\d~2~(33|44)");
```

Could anyone tell what's wrong with the query? Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that hive doesn't support `\d`. Also doubt if it supports other predefined characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can tery this way

```
where mycolumn rlike '.*~[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]~[0-9]~[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9]~[0-9]~      [0-9]~(33|44)';
or mycolumn rlike '.*(33|44)';
it won't work as java with  '\\d~...' or '\d~'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your beginning and ending ticks don't match. You have a backtick and a single quote (`` '` ``)